# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in /home/xxx/public_html/dashboard.php on line 15

Tags: php, syntax, phrase

I am getting following error while running the php code. I am trying to create registration form but it is consistently showing the bellow error message.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in /home/xxx/public_html/dashboard.php on line 15

please help me to solve this problem

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require 'config.php'; 
  if (isset($_POST['register_btn])){
     session_start();
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
     $firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
     $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
     $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password2"]);
     if ($password == $password2){
        $password = md5($password);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, firstName, lastName, email, password, password2) 
       VALUES('$username', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password', '$password2')"; 
       mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       $_SESSION['message'] = "You are successfully logged in";
       $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
       $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;
   }else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "The Two password do not match";
       }

    }


?>
```

Comment: You can even spot the syntax error here in SO looking at the syntax highlighting. You can't yourself?

Comment: `$_POST['register_btn]` is your problem.

Comment: @Scuzzy - Thanks this solved the problem. Can you suggest any free tool that will rectify the simple errors in the php. I am beginner so do not have much knowledge about the tools.

Comment: @PrashantGorule a good PHP IDE should give you feedback straight away with your code. whilst not free I use https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close the single quote `'` in `if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])){`.

Run the below code.

```
<?php
  session_start();
  require 'config.php'; 
  if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])){
     session_start();
     $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
     $firstName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]);
     $lastName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]);
     $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
     $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
     $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password2"]);

    if ($password == $password2){

       $password = md5($password);
       $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, firstName, lastName, email, password, password2) 
       VALUES('$username', '$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password', '$password2')"; 
       mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
       $_SESSION['message'] = "You are successfully logged in";
       $_SESSION['firstName'] = $firstName;
       $_SESSION['lastName'] = $lastName;

    }else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "The Two password do not match";
    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Please don't encourage typo-questions by answering them. They should be closed.